# Splitting Angular CLI application in two builds

Tags: angular, split, configuration, angular-cli

I have an angular solution build on Angular 7 using the CLI. The app has 2 areas. They are not connected in any way, but they use the same code base.

Right now I can go to `http://localhost:4200/app1`, or `http://localhost:4200/app2`.
But they are running on the same instance. I would like to modify my configuration so I could write something like

```
ng build --app=app1
```

and get a standalone solution. Any suggestions to, what I could do ?

Below is my angular.json file. As you can see, I allready have a setup for development, staging, and production. This means that at the moment, I can write

```
ng build --build-optimizer --configuration=staging
```

and get a build for staging environment.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "vhTogo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/vhTogo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputPath": "dist/production",
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputPath": "dist/staging",
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputPath": "dist/development",
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vhTogo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "vhTogo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vhTogo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts", 
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "vhTogo-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "vhTogo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "vhTogo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "vhTogo",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you have 1 root folder in which you have 2 angular application, namely: app1 and app2? and does each of these application contains all angular files like `package.json`, `angular.json`, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're asking actually makes sense. The semantics of `ng serve` make it necessary that all parts of the app being served are compiled. Essentially, you'd be breaking this semantic.

Comment: Everything is under app folder. When I compile for different environments a folder is made for development, and the correct endpoints etc are used. The same for staging and production. So I could make 6 environments. Staging -app1, staging -app2, production -app1 etc

Comment: But I would prefer 3 environments and a flag that just defines if it is app 1 or 2. I might have more apps in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cli` you can generate multiple angular projects in the same codebase(repo) and can build, develop or serve them separately. This way you can enforce microservice architecture at frontend level. This is the best way if you have different products under the same domain and you want to separate them by different routes.

Following are some steps that will help you to build this kind of architecture

1. Generate multiple angular applications : `ng generate application <project-name>` [click](https://angular.io/cli/generate#application-command) here for info
2. Build and serve them separately: `ng build project-name` and `ng serve project-name`
3. Configure routing: to make this routing possible you have to configure `nginx` proxy server.

You have to use location block in nginx script to serve from different projects, the following script is only for demo please refer [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) for full implementation.

```
server {
    listen 4200;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4201;  # your root project
    }

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4202;  # your app1 project
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4203;  # your app2 project
    }

}
```

For production you can serve index.html file of respective project in location block

Comment: This looks promising. I will have a look

Comment: Wow, I just tried, and this is extremely easy to work with. Thanks